# pymssql - connect for each db insert

Tags: python, pymssql

I have a script that tails a log and processes each new line. The result from parsing may or may not be written to a database. The time between writes varies. A write could be done multiple times a second or minutes could go by before writing.

I could set up the connection strategy one of two ways:

1. Open the connection once, using it for each write, reopening on failure, closing on exit
2. Open and close the connection for each write

Option 2 is cleaner and in case of a db failover or other unforeseen connection issue, is more reliable. In some languages there are issues with this approach (usning up sockets, etc). Is there a reason not to connect each time using pymssql?

Comment: constantly opening and closing new connections is expensive, Option 3) make a pool of connections and just recycle once done with the operation

Comment: Hi John G, welcome to stackoverflow! Is the log located on the same server as database? How critical is the data from the log - could you check the file every 5 minut and load the difference?

Comment: Hello @Phillip, lets assume the result is time-sensitive.